# Phpmyadmin SQL result doesn't give the proper result

Tags: php, tinymce

I'm using PHPMyAdmin to manage my database, and I'm currently trying to use one for a project for school.

I'm using a TinyMCE text editor to make people add text. This eventually get stored into the database with some <> attached.

When I want the user to look into his written review, he sees the following https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqzpV.png.

I want the `<p>` to be gone. But it's right from the database.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
} 
else {
    $code = $_POST['view_id']; 
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM review WHERE `Reviewnr` = :code ';
    $std = maakConnectie()->prepare($sql);
    $std->bindValue (":code", $code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $std->execute();
    $result = $std->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($result) ==0) {
            echo 'U heef geen review geschreven, <a href="schrijven_review.php">Klik hier </a> om een review te schrijven';
        }   else {
        echo '<table>';
        foreach ($result as $index => $value){
            $code = $value['Reviewnr'];
        echo '
            <tr> 
                <td class="bold"> Review nr: </td>
                <td> '.$value['Reviewnr'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold"> Laatst gewijzigd op: </td>
                <td> '.$value['Laatste_wijzigingsdatum'].'</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold"> Geplaatst op:</td> 
                <td>'. $value['Plaatsings_datum'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold"> Titel: </td>
                <td>'. $value['Titel'].'</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold"> Review: </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <textarea readonly style="resize: none" rows="10" cols="50" name="review">'. $value['Inhoud'].'</textarea></td> 
            </tr>
                ';
        } 
        echo    '</table>
```

The textarea where it's all about but I figured I post something more so you know it's print from the database.

Please help me get rid of the "< p>" in the text area.

Comment: `var_dump($value)`. does that show the `<p>` tags? If so, then it's coming out of the database like that, and you'll have to figure out how they got there in the first place.

Comment: TinyMCE will be adding them that's what it does, don't use it if you don't want html

Comment: TinyMce adds the `<p>`...Also, this has nothing to do with phpmyadmin

Comment: Sorry Damien, yes I figured he remembered a previous title I put in but I didn't continue writing that one because I solved it. The title is wrong on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strip_tags( )` (https://www.php.net/strip_tags) to remove HTML tags from a string.

I think the best solution for your scenario would be to simply output the HTML outside of the textarea.  Doing that will display the "styled" text/rendered HTML that the user created in TinyMCE.

Here's my suggestion based on your code:

```
} 
else {
    $code = $_POST['view_id']; 
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM review WHERE `Reviewnr` = :code ';
    $std = maakConnectie()->prepare($sql);
    $std->bindValue (":code", $code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $std->execute();
    $result = $std->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($result) ==0) {
            echo 'U heef geen review geschreven, <a href="schrijven_review.php">Klik hier </a> om een review te schrijven';
        }   else {
        echo '<table>';
        foreach ($result as $index => $value){
            $code = $value['Reviewnr'];
        echo '
            <tr> 
                <td class="bold"> Review nr: </td>
                <td> '.$value['Reviewnr'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold"> Laatst gewijzigd op: </td>
                <td> '.$value['Laatste_wijzigingsdatum'].'</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold"> Geplaatst op:</td> 
                <td>'. $value['Plaatsings_datum'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold"> Titel: </td>
                <td>'. $value['Titel'].'</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold"> Review: </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>'. $value['Inhoud'].'</td> 
            </tr>
                ';
        } 
        echo    '</table>
```